# Galaxy Note 2 falls in layout-small category?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resolution

I just can't understand it.  I have tried everything, but it still loads layout-small on my 4.1.2 Galaxy Note 2.

Emulator device setup:

Size: 5.5in Large, Resolution: 720x1280,  Density is xhdpi

and I put this setup to

layout-large.

For some odd reasons,

layout-small is always on my Note 2!  Without it, the phone crashes ????

layout-xlarge is not working either.

What's going on?

**Edit:**

Thanks for Der Golem's comment.  Do not use layout-small, layout-large, and layout-xlarge.

USE

layout-ldpi

layout-mdpi

layout-hdpi

layout-xhdpi

etc....

Comment: Did you try `layout-xhdpi`?

Comment: @ Der Golem, OMG, this is a wake up call for me.  I've done this before but forgot about them.  For some reasons, I was doing layout-xhPdi and it gave me an error.  I went online and saw layout-small, layout-large, and layout-xlarge.  I saw your comment and still putting in layout-xhpdi, then I realized it was xhdpi.  I really appreciate for your help  Der Golem.